# How to remove internal server error phrase from status code 500 pages?

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-8.5, coldfusion-2016

When an error 500 is generated by our application we would like to be in full control of the error page content. However IIS is adding a phrase at the top of the page, `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

Initially an IIS error page was being shown above our error page. In IIS Manager under Error Pages I have removed the page for Status Code 500. This removed the default IIS error page content but left the server error message above our error page.

- I have confirmed that the content isn't being added by the browser
- I confirmed it is not from our app. If I set the IIS error page settings to Detailed Errors the phrase doesn't appear
- We do not want Detailed Errors to be enabled for remote traffic just to fix this for error 500.

How can we disable this phrase?

[image]

Comment: To append to the answer you got... https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/handling-errors/about-error-handling-in-coldfusion.html   ... This may help if you want to customize a display for a given type of error, rather than just use IIS as a blanket to say something went wrong.

Answer (score 6):

The message is appended by IIS. If you don't want IIS to break in on your error handling, switch to the custom error mode in your `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <system.webServer>

        <!-- bypass IIS error handler -->
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

[More documentation about `httpErrors` can be found here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/)

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this in the IIS manager interface?

Comment: At least `errorMode` can be modified through the GUI: `Error Pages` -> `Edit Feature Settings...` (right side) -> `Custom`

Comment: the problem I have with this is that it is trying to pass through all errors and if there is no content from my app, for example in the case of a 404 on an static file, then no content is returned to the browser and the user gets a browser specific error page. I looked to see if there was a way to pass through just 500 error page content but doesn't appear that is supported. Only option I have seen that has the wanted outcome is making the 500.htm error page blank so that when it appears above our error content nothing gets added